# Add ins Name is not displayed in Word 2016

Tags: c#, ms-word, add-in, office-2016

This is a very strange issue that I am not able to see the custom Add-in name in the ribbon of word 2016. it displays just a link without any name and displays all the links under the ribbon on click to the add-in.

The Primary solution I founded is to disable the custom add-in from File-> Options-> Add-Ins->  Manage(Com Add-ins) and enable it again then it works fine.
Add-in is enabled here in by default stage.

[image: Image look like before add-in name display]

I can see all the options of my add-in on click to the highlighted red color block which does not display add in name.

I have developed the add-in in VS 2010 using VSTO.
Is there any setting in word that I have to change for the same or am I Missing something?

Please help..

Comment: Could you please include pictures of the Ribbon before/after disable/reenabling the Ribbon? Is this VSTO or are you using something else to create the addin??